# How to get an HTML link in a javascript confirm() dialog?

Tags: javascript, html, confirm

I need to add an HTML `href` link in the confirm dialog box, but what I am getting is the text of the `href` not the HTML tag).

```
return confirm("Changes to your financial details may affect your GST or tax status for items already for sale via Momento Shop. Please read and confirm the Momento Shop<a target='_blank' href='/pages/terms_print'>terms and conditions.</a>")
```

Output of above code is:

```
Changes to your financial details may affect your GST or tax 
status for items already for sale via Momento Shop. Please 
read and confirm the Momento Shop terms and conditions.
```

But I need terms and conditions become a link (able to be clicked).

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this in the built-in confirmation dialog.

Have a look at some of the available UI libraries around. [jQuery UI's dialog component](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) seems like a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, `alert`, `prompt`, and `confirm` boxes can only contain plain text. Not even images can be appended. I recommend you use a custom modal or custom alert box to display your alert boxes. With custom modals, you can pretty much display any HTML inside.

Answer (score 0):

The default JavaScript `confirm` dialog cannot handle links (or any other rich text for that matter). You may look into using a more complex dialog library.

Answer (score 0):

The confirm() from JS will not do what you  are trying. You need Modal dialogue windows which can be created using some JS tool kit like jQuery